# using ksvm of kernlab package for predicting has an error

Tags: r, predict

I use ksvm function to train the data, but in predicting I have an error,here is the code:

```
 svmmodel4 <- ksvm(svm_train[,1]~., data=svm_train,kernel = "rbfdot",C=2.4,
               kpar=list(sigma=.12),cross=5)
```

**Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) : Variable(s) `' constant. Cannot scale data.**

```
pred <- predict(svmmodel4, svm_test[,-1])
```

**Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'res_var' not found.**

If I add the response variable, it works:

```
pred <- predict(svmmodel4, svm_test)
```

But if you add the response variable,how can it be "predict"? what is wrong with my code? Thanks for your help!

The complete code:

```
library(kernlab)
svmData <- read.csv("svmData.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
svmData$res_var <- as.factor(svmData$res_var)
svm_train <- svmData1[1:2110,]
svm_test <- svmData1[2111:2814,]
svmmodel4 <- ksvm(svm_train[,1]~.,data = svm_train,kernel = "rbfdot",C=2.4, 
              kpar=list(sigma=.12),cross=5)
pred1 <- predict(svmmodel4,svm_test[,-1])
```

Comment: The first column is the response variable, and the others are predictors, this is a sparse data frame.

Comment: any one can help me?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes, I edit the question in a detail.

Comment: Can you also provide the data set "svmData.csv" through a link perhaps?

Comment: It's a "baidu pan":  http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c25nixU.                                       Or I can email you! Thank you for your help!

Comment: the first column is the response variable, and the others are predictors.

Comment: I'm having a problem downloading from Baidu. Can you provide a Dropbox link or similar?

Comment: I have no Dropbox, I can email you if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove your response column from your test dataset. You simply divide your data horizontally, meaning the response column must be in your training and testing datasets, or even validation dataset if you have one.

your function

```
pred <- predict(svmmodel4, svm_test)
```

is working just fine, the predict function will take your data, knowing your factored column, and test the rest against the model. Your training and testing datasets must have the same number of columns, but the number of rows could be different.